# Undefined when i am returning an Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, return, vuex, undefined

I'm doing a getter in VueX, and when i'm returning an object for another function, i have "undefined".

```
  getId: (state) => (LotofID, id) => {
    LotofID.points.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === id)
        return (obj);
   })
```

Basically i have a function like that. When i'm showing `obj` with console.log(obj), i have an object with elements in here. And basically it's working. But when i'm doing a `return` and i'm trying to get the obj in another function

```
var test = []
selectedRowKeys.map(obj => {
    test.push(this.$store.getters.getId(LotofID, obj))
  })
  console.log(test)
```

I have a "undefined" in my variable.
Anyone have an idea of where the problem can be

Comment: `.map()` translates every element in an array/list into something else, hence every path of the callback has to return a value. `.map()` is the absolutely wrong tool here. In both snippets!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): _"The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."_

Comment: @Andreas okay now i understand my error. My mistake, I should have reread the map before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `find` method instead of `map` and return the found item inside your getter:

```
 getId: (state) => (LotofID, id) => {
    return LotofID.points.find(obj => obj.id === id)
}
```